# Database and Toad Data Modeller interaction?

Tags: sql, database, toad

i can connect Toad Data Modeller with SQL Developer and load the tables, but whenever i change a table with SQL-D and after that i open TDM, TDM doesn't show the changes. Is there any option in TDM for this?

Thanks in advance
Georg